# How to append a string in date function first parameter?

Tags: php, date

I have following code

```
$date = '2013-05-11 07:10:14';

echo date('F j, Y at h:i a', strtotime($date); //Not work;  May 11, 2013 at 7:10 am

echo date('F j, Y h:i a', strtotime($date); // This will work when avoiding the `at` from date function.
```

I am trying to append string in date function to display the above date as `May 11, 2013 at 7:10 am`. How to make date at this format using prebuilt date function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the `at` string,

```
echo date('F j, Y \a\t h:i a', strtotime($date));
```

**[DEMO.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9nf7n6)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape any letters that are also formatting queues. You have to double escape the "t" because `\t` is the tab character.

```
echo date('F j, Y \a\\t h:i a');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pb00Gt)

Comment: Without additional escape the code is working. i.e `F j, Y \a\t h:i a`